# Can we use diff() for condition in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, diff, boolean-operations

Actually I am new in Python and just try to do the algorithm below but I got an error.(ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)
I wanna count the time if the values of 'A' are equal.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n=10000000
count=0
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(n,1)),columns=['A'])
check =df['A'].diff().eq(0).astype(int)
if check==0:
   count = count+1
   df['B']=count
print(df)
```

Comment: `check` is a _`Series`_ of values. In this case 1s and 0s. For this reason `if check==0` doesn't really make sense, in a similar way to how `if [0,1,0,0,1] == 0` isn't really what I think you're trying to accomplish. What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I wanna add a column B for counting the time that column A don't change.for example if column A is like this [0,0,0,1,1] , column B will be like this [0,1,2,0,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a boolean index based on where the current value are not equal to the next value.

Sample `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
```

```
   A
0  1
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  1
5  1
6  1
```

Index with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift) + [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum):

```
df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()
```

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Use the index in [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to enumerate each group:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  0  1
4  1  0
5  1  1
6  1  2
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
df['B'] = df.groupby(df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```